# (Angular2 & Typescript) Angular's DatePicker Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, toggle

I'm unable to click on the calendar icon for angular2's datepicker. It kept giving me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AdmissionDialogComponent.html:1)
>       at handleEvent (core.es5.js?de3d:11997)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js?de3d:13458)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js?de3d:13046)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js?de3d:8601)
>       at eval (core.es5.js?de3d:9212)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.eval (platform-browser.es5.js?41b7:2651)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?6524:424)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js?de3d:3881)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?6524:423)

Here are my codes for the start date and end date that can't work:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">

    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="field_treatmentStartDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="treatmentStartDate" ngbDatepicker #tStartDateDp="ngbDatepicker"
            *ngIf="admission.treatment" [(ngModel)]="admission.treatment.startDate" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="tStartDateDp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.treatmentStartDate?.dirty && editForm.controls.treatmentStartDate?.invalid)">
        <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!editForm.controls.treatmentStartDate?.errors?.ZonedDateTimelocal" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.ZonedDateTimelocal">
                                        This field should be a date and time.
                                    </small>
    </div>

    <div [hidden]="!treatmentStartDateIsNull">
        <small class="form-text text-danger">
                                        Missing treatment start date.
                                    </small>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- start date -->



<div class="col-sm-2">

    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="field_treatmentEndDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="treatmentEndDate" ngbDatepicker #tEndDateDp="ngbDatepicker"
            *ngIf="admission.treatment" [(ngModel)]="admission.treatment.endDate" (ngModelChange)="admission?.treatment?.endDate  ? admission.treatment.endDate = $event : null"
        />

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="tEndDateDp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.treatmentEndDate?.dirty && editForm.controls.treatmentEndDate?.invalid)">
        <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!editForm.controls.treatmentEndDate?.errors?.ZonedDateTimelocal" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.ZonedDateTimelocal">
                                        This field should be a date and time.
                                    </small>
    </div>

    <div [hidden]="!treatmentEndDateIsNull">
        <small class="form-text text-danger">
                                        Missing treatment end date.
                                    </small>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- end date -->
```

However, somewhere within the same form, I do have another set of start and end date, and the calendar popup for those are
working perfectly fine.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <!-- Start Date -->
    <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label" jhiTranslate="iconnectSampleAppMonolithApp.admission.startDatetime" for="field_startDate">Start Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="field_startDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" ngbDatepicker #startDateDp="ngbDatepicker"
                [(ngModel)]="admission.startDate" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="startDateDp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.startDate?.dirty && editForm.controls.startDate?.invalid)">
            <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!editForm.controls.startDate?.errors?.ZonedDateTimelocal" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.ZonedDateTimelocal">
                                            This field should be a date and time.
                                        </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <!-- End Datetime -->
    <label class="col-sm-3 form-control-label" jhiTranslate="iconnectSampleAppMonolithApp.admission.endDatetime" for="field_endDate">End Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="field_endDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="endDate" ngbDatepicker #endDateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="admission.endDate"
            />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="endDateDp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.endDate?.dirty && editForm.controls.endDate?.invalid)">
            <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!editForm.controls.endDate?.errors?.ZonedDateTimelocal" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.ZonedDateTimelocal">
                                            This field should be a date and time.
                                        </small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the component.ts file, I have initialized blank values to the admission model in "ngOnInit"

```
this.admission.patient = this.patient;
this.admission.bed = this.bed;
this.admission.bed.ward = this.ward;
this.admission.treatment = this.treatment;
```

So I don't understand why some worked some couldn't work. on ngOnInit function, I have already declared empty attributes to the admission value. When I mean empty, I declared something like

```
treatment: Treatment = new Treatment();
```

Comment: are you declaring the same template variable `startDateDp` twice?

Comment: Hi there, what do you mean? I have declared #startDateDp #endDateDp and #tStartDateDp  #tEndDateDp. Should I not have done that?

Comment: You have *ngIf for the first two datepickers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `*ngIf` statement to the higher level `div`:

```
<div class="input-group" *ngIf="admission.treatment">...
```

And remove from `<input>`

Or use `[hidden]`.

As `*ngIf` removes `<input>` from the DOM when the condition is false and event when the condition is true, it generates the error, because the reference to the local template variable wasn't crated. Don't use template variable and *ngIf together